# NFS client firewall settings and rpcbind

Tags: linux, debian, firewall, nfs

I have a server (Debian 9.6) which mounts an NFSv3 share for backup purposes.

Does it need any specific firewall settings ?

I have found that `rcpbind` is listening on port 111 and 903 and is installed as a dependecy of `nfs-common`. However, if I block all ports with `ufw` and/or kill `rpcbind`, I  can still mount the NFS share.

I don't understand why `nfs-common` depends on `rpcbind` if it works without it. Am I missing anything ? Maybe `rpcbind` is needed for file locking or nfs stats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NFS servers normally run a portmapper or rpcbind daemon to advertise their service endpoints to clients. Clients use the rpcbind daemon to determine:

- What network port each RPC-based service is using
- What transport protocols each RPC-based service supports

The rpcbind daemon uses a well-known port number (111) to help clients find a service endpoint. Although NFS often uses a standard port number (2049), auxiliary services such as the NLM service can choose any unused port number at random.

From section "Mounting through a firewall" of nfs-common [man](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/nfs-common/nfs.5.en.html) page.

The reason why if you block access port and you are able to mount it is probably because the connection as been established from the client to the server, so no incoming connection are generated during mount operation, also when you kill the rpcbind process may the mount operation start it again.

Comment: Actually, `apt-cache depends nfs-common` gives rpcbind as a direct dependency.

Comment: @Max, it was not showed by running reverse dependency apt rdepend nfs-common

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway. As I understand it, `rdepends` shows all the packages depending on a package (reverse dependencies) and `depends` all the dependencies of a package.

Comment: Get it about depends and rdepends, anyway I think my answer (after correct the wrong says on dependency) answer could be considered right, did it?

Comment: I'm not sure. You said that `nfs-common` install the NFS server but most tutorials of NFS server setup suggest the `nfs-kernel-server` package. It's still not clear to me why the NFS client would need rpcbind or NFS server.

Comment: I have update the answer.